# How to solve error with thread file from Visual Studio directory?

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio, invoke

I wrote this little program to use 5 threads to output an ID and wait DELAY time. When I try to execute the program the complier is throwing errors:

**Error C2672    'std::invoke': no matching overloaded function found**
and
**C2893  Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::invoke(_Callable &&,_Types &&...) noexcept()'**

It says they are both on line 39 in the thread file from include folder in Visual Studio directory.
I tried looking up solutions online with no luck. Are you able to help identify the issue?

This is my code for reference:

```
// Multithreading example
// Michal Baran

#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

// Import things we need from the standard library
using std::chrono::milliseconds;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::ofstream;
using std::this_thread::sleep_for;
using std::thread;
using std::vector;
using std::move;

//Declare a struct
struct ThreadArgs
{
    int id{};
    int delay{};
};

//Thread function, prints out thread id and wait delay time 10 times
void myThreadFunc(struct ThreadArgs *args)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout << "This is id: " << args->id << endl;
        sleep_for(milliseconds(args->delay));
        cout << "Wait time: " << args->delay << "ms. " << endl;
    }
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Declare an instance of a struct here
    ThreadArgs args;

    //Assign values into struct, starting with id 0 and delay 500 and rising up to id 5 and delay 900
    for (int t = 0; t < 5; t++)
    {
        int id = -1;
        int delay = 400;
        ThreadArgs th{ id=+1, delay=+100 };
    }

    //Create a vector to hold threads
    vector<thread> vecOfThreads;

    //Add thread object to vector
    vecOfThreads.push_back(thread(myThreadFunc));
    
    //Loop 5 times to create a thread and move it to the vector
    for (int t = 0; t < 5; t++)
    {
        thread th(myThreadFunc, &args);
        vecOfThreads.push_back(move(th));
    }
    

    // Wait for threads to finish and join them
    for (thread& th : vecOfThreads)
    {
        if (th.joinable())
            th.join();
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `std::invoke` function fails to compile because You gave it invalid arguments.

```
//Add thread object to vector
vecOfThreads.push_back(thread(myThreadFunc));
```

Not sure what You meant to do there, but You are attempting to create a new thread using the `myThreadFunc` function, but not giving it the parameter it needs.

If You only meant to create a thread beforehend to run it later, there is no need to. The threads start immediately as they are constructed, and if you want to make a placeholder, just use the default constructor. Then again, that does not seem to be what You were trying to do. Omiting that line seems like the best idea here (unless this is just a snippet and the actual thing does something more).

Comment: Removing the myThreadFunc from the thread constructor made this work. Thank you!

Comment: @MichalBaran Also note that this means that one thread object will be (in the example You posted) left unused forever, meaning You may as well remove the entire line

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.